# On a proof that $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I am trying to understand a proof that $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is cyclic, outlined in Ireland's number theory book, which I quoted as following.

> Finally, on group-theoretic grounds we can see that $\psi(d) \leq \phi(d)$ for $d\mid p-1$. Both $\sum_{d\mid p-1} \psi(d)$ and $\sum_{d\mid p-1} \phi(d)$ are equal to $p - 1$.It follows that
> $\psi(d) = \phi(d)$ for all $d\mid p-1$. In particular, $\psi(p-1) = \phi(p-1)$. For $p > 2$,
> $\phi(d-1) \lt 1$, implying that $\psi(d-1) > 1$. The result follows.

What confused me is that, the author claims that "on group-theoretic grounds we can see that $\psi(d) \leq \phi(d)$ for $d\mid p-1$", where $\psi(d)$ is the number of elements of order $d$ and $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. I can only see "$\psi(d) \leq \phi(d)$" by considering $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ as a field, instead of a group as is stated in the outline. How may one prove $\psi(d) \leq \phi(d)$ based on pure group-theoretic arguments?

Comment: You really mean $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z^\times$ is cyclic?

Comment: You are, I think, mistakenly stating what you are trying to prove. I think you are trying to prove that the *multiplicative group of nonzero elements* in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, not that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic (necessarily under addition).

Comment: You don't have to assume $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} $ is a field. Simply define multiplication in the usual way and prove this is the case. The multiplicative group of  units in a ring $R$ is often denoted $R^\times$ so here it would be $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}^\times$. You will have to use properties of primes to prove this so you won't be able to escape appealing to the properties of primes in some fashion.

Comment: Why it is not cyclic? $Z/pZ\cong Z_p$ is cyclic @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @GGplay But the rest of the arguments given are irrelevant and nonsensical if the question is to prove the additive group of integers modulo $p$ is cyclic. I'm not saying that group isn't cyclic, I'm saying that is not what the argument is trying to prove.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you. I have corrected the description.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you. I have corrected the description.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a group theoretic proof. I will use the notation $\mathbb{Z}_p^*=U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}).$ We'll need two preliminary results: The estrcture theorem for abelian groups and the result that the exponent of a group is the lcm of the orders of the elements of the group, and the maximum of the orders if the group is Abelian. Okay, let's go. We know that the order of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is $\phi(p)=p-1$. By the estructure theorem there exist positive integers $m_1,\ldots,m_r$ such as $m_{i+1}$ divides $m_i$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_{m_r}$. We are going to prove that $m_1=p-1$, which implies that $r=1$ and so on the group is cyclic.  Let's suppose that $m=m_1<p-1$. Since $m$ is the exponent of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, is a multiple of every element of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ (by the previous result), that means that $$(i+p\mathbb{Z})^m=1+p\mathbb{Z},$$ for $1\leq i\leq p-1$.  Equivalently, there exist integers $a_1,\ldots,a_{p-1}$ such as $i^m-1=pa_i$ for $1\leq i\leq p-1$. Note that $a_1=0$, which is not relevant. Since $m+1\leq p-1$ we can write in matrix form  $Ax=b$ the $m+1$ firsts one of this inequalities $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1^2&\cdots &1^m\\ 1&2&2^2&\cdots& 2^m\\ \vdots &\vdots&\vdots&\cdots &\vdots \\ 1&m+1&(m+1)^2&\cdots &(m+1)^m\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\ \vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}pa_1\\pa_2\\\vdots\\pa_{m+1}\end{pmatrix}.$$ The determinant $\delta$ of the matrix $A$ is the Vandermonde's determinant, so $$\delta=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq m+1}(j-i)\not \in p\mathbb{Z}.$$ By Cramer's rule, the adjoint matrix $C=(c_{i,j})$ of $A$ verifies that $$C\cdot \begin{pmatrix} pa_1\\ pa_2\\ \vdots \\pa_m\\ pa_{m+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\delta\\0\\\vdots\\0\\\delta\end{pmatrix}.$$ Matching the $(m+1)$-rows of both members we get that $$\delta=p(c_{m+1,1}a_1+\cdots+c_{m+1,m+1}a_{m+1})\in p\mathbb{Z},$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is it the 10-th proof of this well-known survey?https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf

Comment: I never read that before, but Keith Conrad references this book "E. Bujalance Garc´ıa, J. J. Etayo Gordejuela, and J. M. Gamboa Mutuberr´ıa, Teor´ıa Elemental de Grupos,
Univ. Nac. Educ. Distancia, Madrid, 2002", a book of my professor of Group Theory at Complutense University of Madrid. They taught me the proof as i wrote so seems Keith did the same :)

Comment: Sorry for the misleading description of my question. What confused me is actually a more specific argument used in the proof. But thank you still for your group-theoretic proof, it is quite excellent. Please do not delete it.